# How to dynamically load QML in application from visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qml, qt5

I have a visual studio 2015 project with qml files (Qt5.10), boost and some other libraries which takes quite *some* time to link. In the current setup every qml file is in the qrc file and gets compiled into a qrc_[project_name].cpp file (at least this file contains some raw data related to the qml files). As I understand this makes it possible to deploy the executable without the qml files which will be great, but I would like to prevent the long build times during development.

Is it possible to have the executable load the qml files without rebuilding upon every change?

Removing the qml files from the qrc file doesn't make any difference.

In the main the main.qml gets loaded with:

```
engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
```

In this main.qml other qml files get loaded with:

```
window.pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("Flight.qml"))
```

Comment: you could split your project into 2. One with your c++ files that loads your main.qml and one with just your qml files. So you just need to build your c++ project.

Comment: But if the qml then is changed this will not be reflected in the executable. Because qml files are translated into a qrc_.cpp file which would be is part of the cpp project (that is not regenerated/build). I would like to know how to load qml in the executable qml as text and not as preprocessed cpp file.

Comment: with the split into 2 projects you would end up with an executable that loads your qml files. Your first code example exactly shows how you can load any .qml file from your executable (as 'text')

Comment: I must have configured something wrong with the Qt visual studio plugin then, because before compilation the qml files arr rcc-ed (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/rcc.html) into the cpp and any changes afterwards to the qml are not incorporated into the exe.

Comment: like I said, you split your app into 2 projects one with the c++ stuff and one with the qml stuff. When you make changes to the c++ you need to rebuild the project. When you are making changes to the qml stuff you dont need to build anything (just restart your app if it is running)

Comment: Thanks for your (repeated) advice, I've removed the qrc file from the project and now nothing is being rcc-ed and qml is loaded runtime. This saves me hours of frustrating watching the "Generating code" message. Super!